# PasteSpecial method on range fails

Tags: excel, vba, paste, autofilter

I'm trying to paste a range of cells in another worksheet. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
For i = 1 To MyCount

    wbk.Activate

    Set Criteria = Sheets(IGMSheet).Cells(i, 1)


    Sheets(IGMSheet).Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4)).Copy 'this copies the 3 cells I need

    w.Activate
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData 'remove autofilter

    Selection.AutoFilter

    Range("$A$1:$BM$204").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Criteria.Value

    Range("$BC$1:$BE$204").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial


Next i
```

If I just update a value in the range then it works, but pasting the cells does not.

Kindly advice.

Comment: I don't know exactly what u mean friend. Do u want the format of cell? or value ?

Comment: You are getting that error because you are not copying anything `JUST` before pasting :) Remember Excel has a nagging habit of clearing the clipboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to my comment above, try this...

```
Dim rng As Range

For i = 1 To MyCount
    wbk.Activate
    Set Criteria = Sheets(IGMSheet).Cells(i, 1)

    Set rng = Sheets(IGMSheet).Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4))

    w.Activate
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData 'remove autofilter

    Selection.AutoFilter

    Range("$A$1:$BM$204").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Criteria.Value

    rng.Copy

    Range("$BC$1:$BE$204").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial
Next i
```

There are few other things that I noticed. For example using `.Activate` and unqualified cells `Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4))`

You might also want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179)

Comment: Siddharth, thanks for your reply. The above code works for me, but now when I add data in other sheets in IGMSheet (before they were empty) I am getting a runtime error "application-defined or object-defined error" on line    Set rng = Sheets(IGMSheet).Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 4))    . I have also checked your link, but I cannot refer directly to the sheet name for the object   w     as it can be different each time. Please advice.